# Automate Parent hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dom, loops

```
var classFind= $('.frame').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
if (classfind.hasClass(".class")) {
            return true;
        }
```

I have a class that is located according to this path^... How could I loop through the dom to automate this process with better code readability? If it does not find the .hasclass before it hits a null then simply return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just replace this with...

```
return !!$('.frame').closest('.class').length;
```

The `closest` methods travels up the DOM tree until it finds the element that matches the selector given as its param - and then stops immediately; it will return empty collection of elements (which is still an object, hence its length should be checked) if no such element is found. And `!!` is the same as `Boolean()` call - it's not required, but will make your function return boolean values (`true/false`) instead of `0/1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I like the logic/syntax here however it wasn't really what I was looking for with the existing code base that is set up.

Comment: @Reaper I see; you probably wanted just to get that element, not to check whether it's present or not. In this case simple `$('.frame').closest('.class')` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try someting like this: 
var classFind= $('.frame').closest(".class");

Comment: This was very helpful and worked perfectly with the existing code base. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the closest function, you will not get exact 5 parents, if it is what you want...

This selector will do this.

```
function findEl() {
    if($('.class > * > * > * > * > .frame').length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Test it on:
http://jsfiddle.net/S5juG/1/

Take a look at the child selector:
http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/